# Trying to stop the save process due to an error being promted

Tags: vb.net, save, cancellation

I'm trying to provide on the save button a validation error saying a certain field can't be left blank.

I'm honestly not sure what to try.

```
If txtGEMFeeWBS.Text = "" Or lblGEMFeeWBS.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Error Gem Fee WBS Code must be provided before you can save")
End If

Save_Validation()

If blnValidation = True Then
    If Me.lblInvoiceShipmentID.Text = "" Then
        Save(1)
    Else
        SaveAllKitUnits()
        Save(2)
    End If
End If
```

After where the message box is thrown I want to close out and not hit save data information

Comment: So far your logic seem sound as long as `blnValidation` gets set to `False` if the data doesn't pass the Validation rules. Can you elaborate with what specific problems you are encountering, please? And, I think it would be good if you posted the code in the `Save_Validation` method if it impacts the logic in this save routine

Comment: [ErrorProvider Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about having understood the question but...

It depends on a lot of things. Do you want to completely close the program? Are you inside a method?, etc...

- If you want to close the entire program (I don't think so) just try
  [Application.Exit()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.exit?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Application_Exit)
- If you are on a method you can just use the instruction ***return nothing***
- And in other cases use the [GoTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/goto-statement): Anywhere on the code (almost
  anywhere) you can put **SampleGoToLine:** (don't forget the '**:**') 
  and then call the instruction **GoTo SampleGoToLine** anywhere you
  want or, in your case, after showing the messagebox.
  (The name **SampleGoToLine** is invented, you can put any not [reserved VB keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/keywords/))
- Finally what I would personally do is to reestructure the code. Maybe split validation and save into two different methods or something similar so you can always control what method do you go to depending on certain conditions. (With a simple if-else structure)

Comment: You are right! Personally I don't use the GoTo, but It might help someone on an extreme situation lol